# How to deal with very unstable operating systems?

Tags: restrictions

I'm trying to do some changes on a portable computer, running Windows 7. It fills the entire partition.
However, I'm pretty much unable to run Windows, because it suddenly freezes in a matter of minutes. How can I work with it?
I'm trying to create a new partition and install a new OS on it, while preserving previous data. I have a wireless network and another stable computer.

Comment: Sounds like you need a larger partition.  **Try that first.**

Comment: The hard disk only has one partition, which is entirely occupied by the unstable system.

Comment: 1. Buy a larger drive. 2. Clone the existing drive to the new, larger drive. 3. Replace the existing drive with the new, larger drive. 4. If necessary, extend the volume on the new, larger drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Boot a different OS from a CD/DVD or USB memory stick (for example, some utility distro)
2. Move the data to a safe place
3. Format everything and install a new OS
4. If the system is still unstable, locate the cause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ubuntu (or another Linux distro) to extract the data. If this doesn't work out (if it stills reboots/freezes), you can try upload the data to a cloud storage (Dropbox, OneDrive, Box, Google Drive, etc) and download later.

However, if a upload can't be done, you will have to remove the HDD and extract the data directly through your other computer.